# Как увеличить раздел линукса?

Tags: linux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как увеличить размер '/' раздела? Выделил 20 Гб, пытался сделать "Изменить раздел/переместить" - не получается.

Comment: Для начала загрузитесь не с того же самого раздела, который вы хотите изменить. Например, с LiveCD/LiveUSB

Comment: там есть такая программка Disks, ей измените

Comment: Дело в том, что вы пытаетесь увеличить размер примонтированного раздела. Есть gparted livecd на сайте gparted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По моей практике - root раздел из под системы так просто не расширить, если даже никак. Вам необходимо загрузить LiveCD и только оттуда расширять раздел.
Если Вы планируете часто менять размеры томов, то настраивайте LVM при установке, это сэкономит Вам много времени.